# "monster" turns out to be boys mutated family dog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read in 1977 in an elementary school library, a book of maybe 3 short stories. One with the mutated family dog and one with spider-like creatures destroyed by a crystal. Story had "Boys Life" like characters and morals.